# Stuttering in java vlcj playback of expanding wav files

Tags: java, wav, vlcj

I'm using vlcj in java to playback wav files, that are being expanded by other services. My problem is the following:

when I open an audio file the player knows that the duration is x sec. If it reaches the end it has to reopen (`player.controls().start()`) the file to know the expanded duration. This restart causes a micro stutter in playback (like 0.1 second) but it can be heard, and if the expanding process is slow than the stuttering can happen like every 2 seconds.

I have no way to modify the underlying architecture, so i can not use streaming.

The main issue as I see after hours of research is that vlcj do not provide a way to manually update the duration (that i can calculate by the file size) of the played audio file (it probably loads it to memory on open i guess).

Does somebody tried to implement this kind of playback with success?

Comment: @caprica Yes, exactly! The backend generating these wav files dynamically, and I only got a storage path for them. As a new file gets created I start to play it with minimal delay in the frontend. The files still gets written to as they gets played back. I'm looking for a way to update the file (or just the length property if possible) without reloading it.

Comment: @caprica It's kind of like an audio recording into wav, so the files continuously gets written until an end point (its a streaming alternative because other requirements in the backend - its weird i know). The problem looks like this: when I load a file, libvlc scans the duration eg 15 secs **at that moment**. Playback starts, and when it reaches 15 sec it stops, nonetheless the file **got written to 30 secs during it**. I have to reaload it, and start from the 15th sec to continue.

Comment: @caprica The clients are on Windows and based on Java 9. Wav containers do not specify duration in the file header that's specifically why we can use ("expand") them like this. If I monitor the detected duration through the InfoApi call than it do not show change, stays the same from load to end. It's okay if you don't have a solution, this is really a specific use-case. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After extended research in the topic I concluded that stutterless playback with the above described setup cannot be achieved. It can be optimized greatly, but will never be perfect. The root of the problem is that the length (duration) of the played wav file cannot be set manually, thus reload is a must for rescan.

My solution for this was to implement a [live555 RTSP streaming server](http://www.live555.com/mediaServer/) between the storage and the client. The vlcj player connects to the rtsp stream and plays the (expanding) file seamlessly. The drawbacks are that the playtime needs specific handling, and has less performance (slower response to events).